# Get related articles based on tags in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, tags

I’m trying to display a *related* section based on the article’s tags. Any articles that have similar tags should be displayed.

The idea is to iterate the article’s tags and see if any other articles have those tags.
If yes, then add that article to a `related = []` array of articles I can retrieve later.

---

Article A: `tags: [chris, mark, scott]`
Article B: `tags: [mark, scott]`
Article C: `tags: [alex, mike, john]`
*Article A has as related the Article B and vice-versa.*

---

Here’s the code:

```
files = Dir[ROOT + 'articles/*']

# parse file
def parse(fn)
  res = meta(fn)
  res[:body] = PandocRuby.new(body(fn), from: 'markdown').to_html
  res[:pagedescription] = res[:description]
  res[:taglist] = []
  if res[:tags]
    res[:tags] = res[:tags].map do |x|
      res[:taglist] << '<a href="/%s">%s</a>' % [x, x]
      '<a href="/%s">%s</a>' % [x, x]
    end.join(', ')
  end
  res
end

# get related articles
def related_articles(articles)
  related = []
    articles[:tags].each do |tag|
      articles.each do |item|
        if item[:tags] != nil && item[:tags].include?(tag)
          related << item unless articles.include?(item)
        end
      end
    end
  related
end

articles = files.map {|fn| parse(fn)}.sort_by {|x| x[:date]}

articles = related_articles(articles)
```

Throws this error:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

---

Another thing I tried was this:

```
# To generate related articles
def related_articles(articles)
  related = []
  articles.each do |article|
    article[:tags].each do |tag|
      articles.each do |item|
        if item[:tags] != nil && item[:tags].include?(tag)
          related << item unless articles.include?(item)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  related
end
```

But now the error says:

```
 undefined method `each' for "<a href=\\"/tagname\\">tagname</a>":String (NoMethodError)
```

Help a Ruby noob? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

---

*As an aside to the main question, I tried rewriting the `tag` section of the code, but still no luck:*

```
  res[:taglist] = []
  if res[:tags]
    res[:tags] = res[:tags].map do |x|
      res[:taglist] << '<a href="/' + x + '">' + x + '</a>'
      '<a href="/' + x + '">' + x + '</a>'
    end.join(', ')
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first attempt, the problem is in `articles[:tags]`. `articles` is an array, so you cannot access it using a symbol key.

The second attempt fails because `article[:tags]` is a string (from the `parse` function, you get the original tags, transform to HTML and then join). The `:taglist` key instead contains an array, you could use it.

Finally, the "related" array should be per-article so neither implementation could possibly solve your issue, as both return a single array for all your set of articles.

You probably need a two pass:

```
def parse(fn)
  res = meta(fn)
  res[:body] = PandocRuby.new(body(fn), from: 'markdown').to_html
  res[:pagedescription] = res[:description]
  res[:tags] ||= []  # and don't touch it
  res[:tags_as_links] = res[:tags].map { |x| "<a href=\"/#{x}\">#{x}</a>" }
  res[:tags_as_string] = res[:tags_as_links].join(', ')
  res
end

articles = files.map { |fn| parse(fn) }

# convert each article into a hash like
# {tag1 => [self], tag2 => [self]}
# and then reduce by merge
taggings = articles
           .map { |a| a[:tags].product([[a]]).to_h }
           .reduce { |a, b| a.merge(b) { |_, v1, v2| v1 | v2 } }


# now read them back into the articles
articles.each do |article|
  article[:related] = article[:tags]
                      .flat_map { |tag| taggings[tag] }
                      .uniq
  # remove the article itself
  article[:related] -= [article]
end
```

Comment: The double square brackets in the `map` block are intended. With one square bracket you will not get the right result.

Comment: also the block to merge seems to have too many vertical bars, it's not the case. The third one is simply the `|` method that returns the union of arrays.

Comment: wow! you’re a wizard! it works… thanks for the code, I would have never managed to get it right

Comment: is there a way to write the object back more efficiently? I don’t need the entire object, only the `[:title]` and `[:uri]`… something like this:   

```
  title_and_uri = []
  title_and_uri << {
    title: article[:related].flat_map {|title| article[:title]}.uniq,
    uri: article[:related][:uri] #throws error no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
  }
```
but it doesn’t work

Comment: add `.map { |a| a.slice(:title, :uri) }` after `.uniq` when reading them back.

Comment: Also, if you use ruby >= 2.7, most blocks read better with unnamed args: `.map { _1.slice(:title, :uri) }` etc - but you should also use these on very simple blocks and never nest them, i.e. `.flat_map { taggings[_1] }` and `a.merge(b) { _2 | _3 }` but not in more complex cases or where there is another block inside, otherwise it gets confusing.

Comment: thanks for your time! I learned a lot from your help 